# How do I modify the content of a `RefCell<Option<T>>`?

Tags: rust

I have an `Option<T>` that is shared by several structures and that must be mutable. I'm using a `RefCell` since, as I understand, it is the tool for that job. How do I access (and alter) the content of that `Option<T>` ?

I tried the following:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct S {
    val: i32
}

fn main() {
    let rc: RefCell<Option<S>> = RefCell::new(Some(S{val: 0}));
    if let Some(ref mut s2) = rc.borrow_mut() {
        s2.val += 1;
    }
    println!("{:?}", rc);
}
```

But the compiler won't let me do it:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> <anon>:10:12
   |
10 |     if let Some(ref mut s2) = rc.borrow_mut() {
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `std::cell::RefMut`, found enum `std::option::Option`
   |
   = note: expected type `std::cell::RefMut<'_, std::option::Option<S>, >`
              found type `std::option::Option<_>`
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you [`borrow_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html#method.borrow_mut) the `RefCell`, you get a [`RefMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefMut.html), as the compiler says. To get the value inside it, just use the operator [`deref_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefMut.html#method.deref_mut):

```
use std::cell::RefCell;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct S {
    val: i32
}

fn main() {
    let rc: RefCell<Option<S>> = RefCell::new(Some(S{val: 0}));

    if let Some(ref mut s2) = *rc.borrow_mut() { // deref_mut
        s2.val += 1;
    }
    println!("{:?}", rc);
}
```

Comment: I prefer using `if let Some(s2) = rc.borrow_mut().as_mut() {`, but to each their own.

Comment: @Shepmaster Please feel free to edit my answer and add your own syntax.